# Covariance of two random variables which share a constant component

Tags: covariance

Say I had two random variables, X and Y.

I also have variables A and B, where:

- A = X + Z;
- B = Y + Z; and
- Z is a constant > 0

Am I correct to say cov(X,Y) = cov(A,B)? I'm certain I am overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, and in particular, does not even rely on $Z$ being $>0$. For a (possibly overly pedantic) step-by-step justification, we can use the following calculation:
$$\mathrm{Cov}(A,B) = \mathrm{Cov}(X+Z,Y+Z) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) + \mathrm{Cov}(X,Z) + \mathrm{Cov}(Z,Y) + \mathrm{Cov}(Z,Z)$$
All terms on the right hand side except the first are 0, which follows from the fact that the covariance of anything with a constant is 0 (which in turn follows from the fact that constants can be factored out of expectations):
$$\mathrm{Cov}(X,Z) = \mathbb E[XZ] - \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Z] = \mathbb E[X]Z - \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Z] = \mathbb E[X]Z - \mathbb E[X]Z = 0$$